# problem with external mics on h4n

Tags: microphone, audio-recording

I have an H4n and set up for the first time yesterday with two external mics - worked fine.  Today i updated software and not sure if the problem is related, but when i choose '1 and 2' input buttons (rather than 'mic') on the front of the unit, I am not picking up any sound at all through the two mics.  I have the unit set up in stereo, and I was also wondering how to kill of sound pick up by the built in mics and use only my two NT5s.  I'm new to this and don't know where I've gone wrong but desperate to get it right! any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned on phantom power? Perhaps phantom power was deactivated when updating the software.

If you select "stereo mode" and input 1 2 the internal mics should not pick up any sound, as far as I know.